# Time Calculations: find the time taken, and take its average

Tags: google-sheets

I need to do some calculations. There will be about 100-200 of those 2 entries with different times, competitor numbers and names. I need to calculate the time each competitor's time they took. Then I need to calculate the average of ALL the competitors.

I am using Google Forms to put in the entries, would it be better to stop using Google Forms and enter it into the spreadsheet manually?

[image: Here is the example]

Comment: @I'-'I What do you mean by that?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-a3yOJJstvrvga6qRX-OiB3VG3qLPkYDzOxWp4coP3k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({C1:C200,TIMEVALUE(D1:D200)*IF(B1:B200="End Time",1,-1),E1:E200},"Select Col3,sum(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col3 format sum(Col2) '[h]:m'"))
```

Assuming, No competitions were done past mid night, this should work.